# spark populate column values in first table from value present in second table but in different columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pysaprk ,I have two tables and I am trying to populate value against
some columns which are present in other table but in different columns

**Table1** original_val is the column in which person row's value are missing,see below

```
    #+-------------+----------+----------------+
    #| name        | Value    | original_val   |
    #+-------------+----------+----------------+-
    #|Movie_name   |  RHDM    |    123         | 
    #|teacher_name |  Rohit   |    345         | 
    #|  person     |  kerry   |                |
    #|  person     |  Suzen   |                |
    #|  person     |  JD_Jem  |                |
    #|             |          |                |
```

**Table2** has below structure contains person name and somevalue for it, note all person name and value are spread across different column like below

```
#+-----------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+--------+
#| key       | value_1  | key2      |value_2  |key3      |value_3 |
#+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------------+--------+
#|  kerry    |  540     |           |         |  JD_Jem  |  888   |
#|           |          |  Suzen    |  123    |          |        |
#|           |          |           |         |          |        |
```

**output expected**
in table1 I am looking below output kerry,Suzen,JD_Jem values which are missing need to
populate from Table2 like below

```
#+-------------+----------+----------------+
#| name        | Value    | original_val   |
#+-------------+----------+----------------+-
#|Movie_name   |  RHDM    |    123         | 
#|teacher_name |  Rohit   |    345         | 
#|  person     |  kerry   |    540         |
#|  person     |  Suzen   |    123         |
#|  person     |  JD_Jem  |    888         |
#|             |          |                |
```

I have tried below but not getting exact expected result

```
select distinct t1.*,t2.value_1 as id from Table1 as t1 left join Table2 t2
on t1.Value=t2.key
union 
select distinct t1.*,t2.value_2 as id from Table1 as t1 left join Table2 t2
on t1.Value=t2.key2
union 
select distinct t1.*,t2.value_3 as id from Table1 as t1 left join Table2 t2
on t1.Value=t2.key3
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: edited with mine efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing a dataframe api based solution.
Assuming table1_df and table2_df

```
#bring your table2 to proper format 
key_value_df = table2_df.select("key","value_1")
              .union(table2_df.select("key2","value_2"))
              .union(table2_df.select("key3","value_3"))
              # .filter ( your logic to remove empty/nulll fields)

#+-----------+----------+
#| key       | value_1  |
#+-----------+----------+
#|  kerry    |  540     |  
#|           |          |
#|           |          |
#|  Suzen    |  123     |
#|           |          |
#|  JD_Jem   |  888     |
     
         
# Now join 
joined_df = table1_df.join(key_value_df,table1_df.Value ==  key_value_df.key,"left")

 #+-------------+----------+----------------+-----------+----------+
 #| name        | Value    | original_val   | key       | value_1  |
 #+-------------+----------+----------------+-----------+----------+

#now fill in the values from value_1 into original_val for all empty original_val

final_df =  joined_df.withColumn('original_val', 
            F.when(F.col("original_val") == "", F.col("value_1"))
            .otherwise(F.col("original_val")))
            .drop("key","value_1")
```

you can replace the `F.col("original_val") == ""` with appropriate condition.

Comment: this logic help me to convert mine logic further which is in spark sql ,thanks